# optimal normalization of dataframe in pandas using std of backward looking window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following DataFrame:

```
               var
date              
1900-01-31  0.0357
1900-02-28  0.0362
1900-03-31  0.0371
1900-04-30  0.0379
1900-05-31  0.0410
1900-06-30  0.0435
1900-07-31  0.0448
1900-08-31  0.0455
1900-09-30  0.0478
1900-10-31  0.0474
1900-11-30  0.0451
1900-12-31  0.0437
1901-01-31  0.0427
1901-02-28  0.0418
1901-03-31  0.0406
1901-04-30  0.0377
1901-05-31  0.0399
1901-06-30  0.0365
1901-07-31  0.0393
1901-08-31  0.0390
```

I need to normalize these values by dividing each one by their standard deviations using a backward-looking window of 500 days (~16 months, means I can use a backwards splice of size 16). There are two ways to do this from what I've researched:

1. The first that came to mind is to use `DF.rolling_std()` to make a new dataframe, iterate over both, divide accordingly and replace the value in the original DataFrame with the result of the division.
2. The second idea I had was to iterate over the original Dataframe, make a new DF that is simply all values over the last 16 months, calculate the STD of that, and divide & store accordingly.

However, I'm not sure which is more efficient, or if either of these are efficient compared to other solutions. Here is the idea I'm running with:

```
def normalize(df, window=16):
    columnName = list(df.columns.values)[0]
    df[[columnName]] = df[[columnName]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    df['std'] = df.rolling(window=16).std()
    df[columnName] = df.apply(lambda row: float(row[columnName])/row['std'], axis=1)
    return df.loc[:, :columnName]
```

Output:

```
                  var
date                 
1900-01-31        NaN
1900-02-28        NaN
1900-03-31        NaN
1900-04-30        NaN
1900-05-31        NaN
1900-06-30        NaN
1900-07-31        NaN
1900-08-31        NaN
1900-09-30        NaN
1900-10-31        NaN
1900-11-30        NaN
1900-12-31        NaN
1901-01-31        NaN
1901-02-28        NaN
1901-03-31        NaN
1901-04-30   9.565440
1901-05-31  10.969396
1901-06-30  10.122305
1901-07-31  11.416832
1901-08-31  11.604732
```

Note that this output is good. I haven't manually checked to see if the values are actually correct, but they seem accurate. My question is if there is a more efficient/intuitive way to perform this operation.

Comment: *Better*? Does it work? What are errors/undesired result?

Comment: This works. Updating the post with output.

Comment: Are there more than one *var*? If not, no need for `apply` or *columnName*: `df['std'] = df.rolling(window=16).std(); df['var'] = df['var'] / df['std']`